# Debian Input/Output Error

Tags: debian, xfce

I have a Debian 10 Xfce4.

Recently out of nowhere I will get an **Input/Output error**. Every button, application, buttons in panel is showing Input/Output error. It gets fixed when I hard restart it. This is becoming really annoying.

I was trying window managers like Dwm, i3 on the system, then removed them. I don't no what to do. Can you help me figure it out?

Comment: Input/output error is indicative of a disk failure. Have you checked SMART for the disk?

Comment: No, i don't think i know how to do that.

Comment: install `smartmontools` - then use `smartctl`

Comment: Okay i installed it. How to use it?

Comment: `smartctl -a /dev/sda` (a read-only "safe" operation but one you'll need to run as root), replacing `/dev/sda` with the device name of the problematic disk. Find the two sections "START OF INFORMATION SECTION" and "Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds", and add these to your question